# Ternary operator not working properly in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, ternary-operator

So I have a component called PrivateRoute.js that basically protects some routes and redirects a user to the login page if they are not logged in ,I would like to display an alert message inside the ternary operator, my alert goes through but after a few seconds I get an error

**PrivateRoute**

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
    return ( 
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
        /*If "IsLoggedIn" is located inside the local storage(user logged in), then render the component defined by PrivateRoute */
            localStorage.getItem("IsLoggedIn")  ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : alert('You must be logged in to do that!') (  //else if there's no authenticated user, redirect the user to the signin route 
            <Redirect 
              to='/signin' 
            /> 
          ) 
        }
      />
    );
  }
```

this is the error I get in react:

[image: React Error]

How do I display an alert inside the ternary operator without getting this error?

Comment: You have `alert("message")(<component />)`. So it's going to call `alert` and then try to call what `alert` returns. But calling `alert` jus gives you `undefined`, which can't be called.  Nothing to do with React.

Comment: Happens when you do not use semicolons.... Your code is basically `var foo = alert('x'); foo(<render>)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript sees `alert(...) (...)` as if you want to call the return value of `alert` as a function, but `alert` doesn't return a function. That's what the error is telling you.

If you want to evaluate multiple expressions in sequence, you can use the [**comma operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

```
condition ? case1 : (alert('some message'), <Redirect ... />)
//                  ^                     ^                 ^
```

---

You can achieve the same by moving the `alert` call before the `return` statement, which makes your code simpler too:

```
render() {
  const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("IsLoggedIn");
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    alert(...);
  }

  return <Route ... />;
}
```

Note that `localStorage` only stores string values, so you probably need to convert the return value of `localStorage.getItem("IsLoggedIn")` to an actual boolean value.

---

Having said all that, note that you should avoid using `alert` since it is blocking.

Comment: You *can*, but much bettter to move that logic out of the JSX and into a function body for `render`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Right.